# Both buttons getting the same icon (always the icon of the first) although 2 different icons set for each

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg, button, icons

I am trying to build a basic slideshow component in React. There are 2 buttons. I have the LeftArrow and RightArrow icons as jsx components. Now, no matter which icon is set to the second button, it always copies the icon of the first one. Here is the code :

Slider.jsx :

```
import React from 'react'
import RightArrow from "../assets/icons/RightArrow"
import LeftArrow from "../assets/icons/LeftArrow"

function Slider() {
  return (
    <section className='home--section-wrapper'>
        <button><LeftArrow/></button>
        <button><RightArrow/></button>
    </section>
  )
}

export default Slider
```

RightArrow.jsx :

```
import React from 'react'

function RightArrow() {
  return (
    <svg width="100" height="100" viewBox="0 0 100 100" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlnsXlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
      <rect width="100" height="100" fill="url(#pattern0)"/>
      <defs>
      <pattern id="pattern0" patternContentUnits="objectBoundingBox" width="1" height="1">
      <use xlinkHref="#image0_216_2" transform="scale(0.01)"/>
      </pattern>
      <image id="image0_216_2" width="100" height="100" xlinkHref="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAGQAAABkCAYAAABw4pVUAAAACXBIWXMAAAsTAAALEwEAmpwYAAABIklEQVR4nO3dMU7EMABFwT0SXIdut+IGtFycfQghCqSlzheZ6dxZebHTRPblAgAAAAAAwGGqJ49/RPVe3avXo+dyen3H+CHKkarn6qPfvsa307+pB0a5PohipRwpUfYkyp5E2ZMoexJlT6LsSZQ9ibInUfYkyp5E2ZMoexJlT6LsSZQ9ibInUfYkyp5E2ZMoexJlT6LsSZQ9ibInUfYkyp5E2VPd/vjB+3r03E6rxyvla/xy9NxOKUF2ZMvakY/6jsTYkRg7EmNHYuxIjB2JsSMxdiTGjsTYkRg7EmNHYuxIjB2JsSMxdiTGjsTYkRg7EmNHYuxIjB2JsSMxdiTGjsTYkRg7EmNHDuPfU705hH8zyt2FLkNy5REAAAAAAMDlv/kEAny3FazsZ1QAAAAASUVORK5CYII="/>
      </defs>
    </svg>
  )
}

export default RightArrow
```

LeftArrow.jsx :

```
import React from 'react'

function LeftArrow() {
  return (
    <svg width="100" height="100" viewBox="0 0 100 100" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlnsXlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
      <rect width="100" height="100" fill="url(#pattern0)"/>
      <defs>
      <pattern id="pattern0" patternContentUnits="objectBoundingBox" width="1" height="1">
      <use xlinkHref="#image0_216_3" transform="scale(0.01)"/>
      </pattern>
      <image id="image0_216_3" width="100" height="100" xlinkHref="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAGQAAABkCAYAAABw4pVUAAAACXBIWXMAAAsTAAALEwEAmpwYAAABH0lEQVR4nO3dwU3DQBRF0ZQEtVABWdEFW3pGcFGkREhQgB/knN149aWr8Sxs2acTAAAAAAAA/0r1cPQMXFXP1Uf1drvG8TFuRDkwxvlHjK7rx8OGulf93hkXn9XL0bPdncTYkRg7EmNHYuxIjB2JsSMxdiTGjsTYkRg7EmNHYuxIjB2JsSMxdiTGjsTYkRg7EmNHYuxIjB1iDBFjiBhDxBgixhAx9mNc1uejZ7s71VP17sXnEYIMcssa5FAfJMogUQaJMkiUQaIMygOqPYmyJ1H2JMqeRNmTKHsSZU+i7EmUPYmyJ1H2JMqeRNmTKHsSZU+i7EmUPYmyJ1H2JMqeRNmTKHvyMf4/sVNej57p7vUdRYwV+eURAAAAAADA6Uhfe323E5njGc8AAAAASUVORK5CYII="/>
      </defs>
    </svg>
  )
}

export default LeftArrow
```

I already tried :

1. to clean the browser cache
2. to insert icons as svg directly into the Slider.jsx, without creating the components.
3. using different browsers
4. checked in dev tools, it shows as the correct icon is being rendered

I know there are other ways to do it, but I simply wanna know what is wrong here.
I feel like I am missing out something obvious. So any help would be appreciated.